# Excel VBA: How can I select all of my Charts and change their sizes to a different, yet uniform size?

Tags: excel, vba, charts, formatting

The problem: I've got a large file containing about 250 charts, I've been formatting the charts with code looking like this=

```
         With chrt
            .SetSourceData Source:=rChartData.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 3)

            .SetElement msoElementChartTitleCenteredOverlay
            .ChartTitle.Caption = cl.Value

            .PlotArea.Height = .PlotArea.Height - .ChartTitle.Height
            .PlotArea.Top = .PlotArea.Top + .ChartTitle.Height

            .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Measured"""
            .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""Modeled"""

            .SeriesCollection(1).MarkerStyle = -4142
            .SeriesCollection(2).MarkerStyle = -4142
            
            .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 14650
            .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 40000
            .Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 1800
            .Axes(xlCategory).MinorUnitIsAuto = True

            .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
                .Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Text = "Stress Periods"
            .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleRotated)
                .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Cubic Feet/Sec"
       
       End With
```

Then it goes on its merry loop to finish the other 249 charts. But I also need all of them to be larger than the default size Excel gives me. What is the correct code terminology to extend my chart to a larger size such as this from A to B?

[image]

Comment: can you try chrt.Parent.Width = SOMEVALUE?

Answer (score 0):

I found the property to add to the umbrella With statement:

```
          .ChartArea.Width = [desired width, IN POINTS, of the object]
```